# Oauth C Library

Tags: c, twitter, oauth

I am looking for a simple oauth source for a c program. (Only for twitter status updates) How can i do that at least? Or please point me a simple program that does this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [liboauth](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/).  There are some examples included with the source, such as [oauthexample.c](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/source/browse/code/c/liboauth/tests/oauthexample.c).

Answer (score 0):

this is the PHP PECL OAuth Extension - open source extension written in C, implementing provider and client. Included in the archive are .c source files:

http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a mini C library using liboauth and json-c called [twitc](https://github.com/sinemetu1/twitc).

There is a basic example in main.c and instructions in the README. Feel free to file a github issue if you have any problems.